# How can I create a common file between JavaScript and C/C++ for a constant?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, configuration

I have a C++ program with the following in the header file: 
`#define VARIABLE_X 100`

Also, a JavaScript file with the global: `VARIABLE_X = 100;`

These values will always need to be the same.

Instead of having to change them in both places (.h and .js), I need a common file where both can get this value, thus only needing to be changed in one place.

How can I create a common file between JavaScript and C/C++........ for a #define/constant ?

Thank You.

Comment: +1, I've faced this dilemma for inter-language constant storage before w/ no good solution.

Comment: Jason, what are your thoughts on Anon's answer? Is this a better solution than you ended at? Or is it that there really isn't a way to have a "shared file" between the two vs. build generating files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an actual script-driven build process, right?

Just stick a rule in your makefile that regenerates `constants.h` if `constants.js` has been changed.

Comment: +1. But please, while you're at it, use real constants in the C++ program: 'const int VARIABLE_X = 100;' (or whatever type is appropriate rather than 'int') and not a #define. #define is a literal copy-and-paste. Use actual language features instead, when they exist.

Comment: Anon, please pardon my lack of knowledge in build processes but would it be possible to change the particular variable in JS and have it update a specific #define in the .h in a make file rule? Could you elaborate please. Thank You.

Comment: @Tommy: In VS, if you go to the Project page, and then the Build tab, you can define pre- and post-build steps. Anything you set up in the pre-build section will be run by Visual Studio before it actually builds anything - so you can write a quick program to take the JS file, and create the new header file based on that, and have Visual Studio automatically do that every time it goes to build the project.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Good point, but I'd go one step further and declare `static const int VARIABLE_X = 100;` - otherwise you might end up with multiple definitions which the linker will reject (rightfully).

Answer (score 3):

What build system are you using? Build system is a very good place for this type of stuff.

Comment: Ding old school CGI on Visual Studio (server side code) and JavaScript/HTML, basically, in note pad. (yes I know)

Comment: @Tommy I'm not an expert on Microsoft tools, but I'm pretty sure that it can actually be done in VS build system.

Comment: +1. Even for rudimentary projects that you run by yourself, a build system is a win for many reasons including this.

Comment: So there is some option in VS to do this? What is this type of option called?

Answer (score 2):

This method uses a separate file for each data type, but allows you to include specially formatted javascript files in a C/C++ header.

You can `#define` macros in C/C++ to change identifiers as needed.  For javascript the obvious candidate is `var` since it is only needed in javascript ... it can be redefined as necessary to any c type.  Normally I wouldn't recommend using `new Array()` in javascript, but since C/C++ use `{...}` to initialize arrays while javascript uses `[...]`, it is a necessary evil that allows you to wrap them.

## <kbd>c-header.h</kbd>

```
//constant integers
#define var const int
#include "int-consts.js"
#undef var

//constant strings
#define var const char*
#include "string-consts.js"
#undef var

//arrays of strings
#define var const char**
#define new (const char*[])
#define Array(...)  {__VA_ARGS__}
#include "string-arrays.js"
#undef new
#undef var

//and so forth for other types
```

<kbd>int-consts.js</kbd>

```
var swapMagicOffset = 4086;
```

<kbd>string-consts.js</kbd>

```
var swapMagic = "SWAP-SPACE";
var swapMagic2 = "SWAPSPACE2";
```

<kbd>string-arrays.js</kbd>

```
var cars = new Array("Ford", "Chevy", "Dodge");
```

**Edit:**
On further thought you can do more than just keep your constants in sync.  You can even write code that can run as both javascript and C using a little known difference between the two languages.  In C you can use a '\' which continues on the next line, thus allowing us to use `*\newline/` to end a comment in C (compile with -Wno-comment to ignore warnings in Clang), but since js doesn't follow the same rules, it will keep going as a comment until it finds an actual '*/' token.

```
/* C comment ends with the '/' on next line but js comment is open  *\
/ //BEGIN C Block
#define function int
/* This ends the original js comment, but we add an opening '/*' for C  */

/*Most compilers can build K&R style C with parameters like this:*/
function volume(x,y,z)/**\
/int x,y,z;/**/{return x*y*z;}

/**\
/
#undef function
/**/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, for lots of reasons. However there is a simple solution: have a function that generates a Javascript file out of the constants, and dynamically load that in your Javascript.

Something as simple as:

```
 printf("VARIABLE_X = %d;\n", VARIABLE_X);
```

If it becomes a maintenance hassle, you can write a simple function to generate both the .h file and the .js file out of some common format.

Comment: Never thought about that. To load this generated javascript just include it in the html or is there another way to "load it" in my current JavaScript? thanks.

Comment: Depends a lot on the environment you are working in. ASP.NET? PHP? Django? Some other environment? Sounds like some sort of custom environment if you are using C++. Last I saw people doing that it was CGI. But I probably am missing something.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your comment above, you are using low level CGI. In that case just set the source for the <script> to point to a dynamically generated javascript file, using something like the above.